# Why would trivial packages be made dependant on dpkg?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I've recently been exploring minimal systems; taking a single package and working through the the dependencies it would need to support it (and nothing more).

I was surprised to see `dpkg` appearing as a dependency in more than one place, and for packages that have virtually no reason to have a dependency.  For example [`readline-common`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/readline-common).  This package only contains the files:

```
/usr/share/readline/inputrc
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/readline-common
/usr/share/doc/readline-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/readline-common/copyright
/usr/share/doc/readline-common/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/readline-common/inputrc.arrows
/usr/share/man/man3/readline.3readline.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/history.3readline.gz
/usr/share/info/rluserman.info.gz
```

Neither it's `postinst` nor `prerm` scripts reference `dpkg` or anything obviously related to it.

Likewise [`python3-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/python3-minimal/download).

I'm just curious to understand why `dpkg` would appear as a dependency of trivial packages?

Answer (score -1):

Probably because it depends upon a specific or minimum version of `dpkg`.  Normally, dpkg doesn't need to be listed as a dependency because it is tagged `Essential: yes` - it's not possible to have a Debian system that doesn't have `dpkg` installed unless you go to extraordinary lengths to break your system (and then it's not really a Debian system any more, it's a broken mess).

e.g. if you look at the Depends: line for `python3-minimal`, it says:

```
Depends: dpkg (>= 1.13.20)
```

That means it requires version 1.13.20 of `dpkg` or newer.  This versioned dependency ensures that `python3-minimal` won't be installed or upgraded until at least that version is installed.

I don't know **why** `python3-minimal` requires that version of `dpkg`.  I can only assume that the `python3-minimal` package maintainers knew, or discovered, that it would break with any earlier version.   Most likely, one of its pre/post scripts requires a feature that wasn't in `dpkg` until version 1.13.20.

If I really wanted to know, which I actually don't :-), I could read the changelogs in `/usr/share/doc/python3-minimal`, or the bug report history on [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=both;package=python3-minimal).  They're the most likely places to find some mention of the reason.  Or maybe in the [debian-devel](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/) archives or the mailing lists and docs and policies of the [Debian Python Team](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/PythonTeam)

---

Similarly, `readline-common` depends on `dpkg` version 1.15.4 or newer OR `install-info`:

```
Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4) | install-info
```

If you look in `/usr/share/doc/dpkg`, you'll find almost 100 mentions of install-info.  The changelog entry for 1.15.4 (dated 06 Sep 2009) says:

> - Replace install-info by a wrapper around GNU's install-info. The
>   wrapper
>   will be dropped in squeeze+1. dpkg now Breaks: old versions of
>   info-browsers that do not depend on the new install-info package
>   that provides the real functionality. Closes: #9771, #523980

Comment: Forgive me, but this answer seems to be saying nothing but "because there is a dependency" and "I don't want to know why".  I've already ruled out pre/post install scripts.

Comment: The answer is saying "because there is a **versioned** dependency" (and that it's not normally necessary to depend on dpkg because it's tagged Essential). If you want to know more than that for any specific package(s) then you're going to have to investigate the individual details - changelogs, bug reports, mailing lists, etc - for those package(s).  It's impossible to be any more specific than that because each one will have its own reason(s) for requiring a specific minimum version of dpkg. I provided a list of good places to look for those details, and even found the changelog for one pkg.

Comment: There is no one answer to your question.  You asked a generic question about why dpkg is appearing as a dependency in several packages for no apparent reason, with two examples.  I gave you a generic answer for why that happens ("needs a specific version of dpkg"), with specific details on one package (readline-common needs dpkg >= 1.15.4, due to changes to `install-info` in dpkg), and details on how to investigate any others yourself.  I'm not going to trawl through all packages that depend on dpkg (> 900) and figure out all the individual reasons why just to satisfy your idle curiosity.

Comment: 1. The pattern IS "requires a specific version of dpkg".  That's it.  That's the pattern.   How many more times do you need to be told that?   2. You're focusing on one throwaway sentence in one tiny part of my answer - the rest of my answer tells you exactly what you asked for and even looked up one specific answer for you.  You want details on that python3-minimal package or any other package, you can investigate it yourself. I've wasted enough of my time on your quibbling.

Comment: This reminds me of that ancient proverb: Give a man a fish and he'll have a meal.  Teach him how to fish and he'll whine about not getting fed for free.

Comment: Last comment because this is getting a bit rediculous.  You may note the word "trivial" in the question. If you look at the package content I'm referring to you will see they have next to no programmatic content, their pre/post scripts are trivial and their control meta file appears pretty trivial too. These packages have next to no content so how on earth are they incompatible with previous dpkg versions?!! And please believe me, I've already spent hours trawling through bug reports in hope of finding something. I'm not asking "for free" I'm asking because I hope someone has inside knowledge.

Comment: **install-info**. readline-common has a .info file, `/usr/share/info/rluserman.info.gz`. You listed it yourself in your question.  dpkg  1.15.4 replaces its own install-info with a wrapper around GNU's install-info. That's why I block-quoted the relevant changelog entry - read bugs 9771 and 523980 that it mentions. Sometimes you have to make an effort to understand context and history before things make sense.  python3-minimal isn't as obvious, you'll have to look in the bugs closed by dpkg 1.13.20 AND changelogs for python3-minimal AND possibly mailing list etc archives from around that time.